# Is it possible to get assistant voice on Android Auto sounding good without data?

Tags: bluetooth, google-maps, google-maps-navigation, google-assistant, android-auto

I don't use data to use AA (I have offline Spotify and offline Maps) for the most part.

As a result the assistant voice sounds like a robot from the 1970s.

Anyway to "download" the good assistant voices or force Android Auto to sound good?

I have tried to set the voice sampling in Android Auto up to 48kHz.

Comment: Google's text-to-speech engine is an AI based cloud system: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech Typically such systems make use of special AI hardware chips. Without them speech generation would require a high-end computer. Some recent high-end smartphones also have AI chips, but I don't know if Google's offline speech generator can make use of them.

Comment: Still, why does it sound so so much better on bluetooth with using Android Auto? That is all I want.

Comment: 1.It's an old Google issue with no solution [here](https://support.google.com/androidauto/thread/4171864?hl=en) 2. Re: Your comment above . Some people in link above complained about the same thing (sounding fine on Bluetooth) 3.  Asking *why* it sounds better on Bluetooth is off topic IMO, because it is *Android independent*